# Error 405 al consumir servicio Api Rest

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar consumir un servicio Api Rest desde Angular 6, mi código de Angular es el siguiente:

```
GuardarDatos(datos:General):Observable<string> {

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
    })
};
let url =`${Conexion.URL}${Operacion.guardardatos}`;
let header =this.getHeaders();
return this.http.post<string>(url,datos,httpOptions).pipe();
```

Tengo el ApiRest de la siguiente manera:

```
[ActionName("TasaPreferTdc")]
[HttpPost]
public string CrearTasaPrefer([FromBody]DatoGeneral objDatoGeneral)
{ return "";}
```

Al realizar el llamado me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

habilitar `CORS` realiznado los siguientes pasos

1. Instalar el  paquete nuget para `CORS`: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`.
2. Modifica tu archivo `WebApiConfig.cs` el método `Register` agregando la siguiente línea

   ```
   config.EnableCors();
   ```
3. Puedes habilitar `CORS` en tu controlador de la siguiente forma

   ```
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Cors;

   namespace CORSWithWebAPI.Controllers
   {
      [EnableCors(origins: "http://client.domain", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
      public class SampleController : ApiController
      {
         public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }

        [DisableCors]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutItem(int id) { ... }   
      }
   }
   ```
4. Puedes habilitar `CORS` a nivel de acción

   ```
   public class SampleController : ApiController
   {
       [EnableCors(origins: "http://client.domain", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
       public HttpResponseMessage GetSample(int id) { ... }
   }
   ```
5. Puedes habilitarlo de forma global modificando el punto 1:

   ```
   public static class WebApiConfig
   { 
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
         var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("client.domain", "*", "*");
         config.EnableCors(cors);
      }
   }
   ```
6. Inclusive desde `web.config`

   ```
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que de lo que realmente se está quejando es de que tu servidor no está aceptando una petición de tipo OPTIONS, no el POST que haces con tu código.

Esa petición OPTIONS se manda por parte del navegador como parte del control de peticiones de orígenes cruzados (lo que en inglés llaman CORS), es decir, se incluye cuando se está solicitando un recurso a un servidor que no es el que ha generado la página (en tu caso, estás sirviendo la página desde localhost:4200 y estás haciendo el POST a localhost:49143).

Revisa la configuración de tu servidor IIS para que acepte las requests de tipo OPTIONS.

PD: Te dejo [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) para que le eches un vistazo

Comment: De hecho lo que realiza el OP es por método `POST` con la instrucción `return this.http.post<string>(url,datos,httpOptions).pipe();`